How does one enforce a chron-job to be executed exactly at every possible 5 minute mark (0:00, 0:05, 0:10) regardless of the chron-job's start time?
I have a JavaScript function of chrome extension that I need to run at exact 5-minute intervals, synchronized with the current time. For example, it should run at 5:00, 5:05, 5:10, and so on, regardless of when the script starts running.
Here is the approach I am trying to implement:
Calculate the delay until the next 5-minute mark.
Use setTimeout to call the function at the next 5-minute mark.
Set up a setInterval to call the function every 5 minutes after the initial timeout.
Here is a simplified version of the code to demonstrate the issue:

function myFunction() {
    console.log("Function executed at:", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}

function checkTimeAndRunMainFunction() {
    let now = new Date();
    let minutes = now.getMinutes();
    let seconds = now.getSeconds();

    if (seconds === 0 && minutes % 5 === 0) {
        // Run the main function immediately
        myFunction();
    }
}

function calculateDelayToNextFiveMinuteMark() {
    let now = new Date();
    let millisecondsUntilNextFiveMinuteMark = (5 - (now.getMinutes() % 5)) * 60 * 1000 - now.getSeconds() * 1000 - now.getMilliseconds();
    return millisecondsUntilNextFiveMinuteMark;
}

// Set an initial timeout to synchronize with the next 5-minute mark
setTimeout(function() {
    checkTimeAndRunMainFunction();
    // Set an interval to check the time every 5 minutes after the initial call
    setInterval(checkTimeAndRunMainFunction, 5 * 60 * 1000);
}, calculateDelayToNextFiveMinuteMark());

The problem I am facing is that setInterval(checkTimeAndRunMainFunction, 1000); counts every second from the moment the user runs the code, and it does not synchronize with the actual clock's seconds, resulting in the condition if (seconds === 0 && minutes % 5 === 0) not being met precisely.
How can I ensure that my function runs exactly at the 5-minute marks (e.g., 5:00, 5:05, 5:10) regardless of when the script starts running?

There's no setInterval(checkTimeAndRunMainFunction, 1000) in the posted code. Maybe you have an old version of the content script running in the page? Reload the extension in chrome://extensions page and reload the tab. See also How to remove orphaned script after Chrome extension update

@woxxom it uses setTimeout to determine the first run.

@Hamed you pass the wrong amount of milliseconds (time passed since the last run) to the initial call. Use 300000 - (Date.now() % 300000) for the setTimeout duration.

@Christopher, my point is that the question mentions a part of code that doesn't exist.

@woxxom his challenge is, when the script is execute at 0.995 seconds (or the first run is executed when Date.now() ends on 99N milliseconds), the check (min = 0 & secs = 0) can fail. Because the results of getSeconds() and getMilliseconds() inside the callback can be 1 and >=0 at the time of execution.

I wasn't commenting on the challenge. My comment was about the discrepancy in the text of the question and the posted code.

Here simple script that runs every 5 minute and adjust next start time on every run


(function loop() {
  const date = new Date();
  const wait = 300000 - date % 300000
  console.log(date, wait);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(new Date())

    loop();
    // your code here
  }, wait);
})();




Fails if the remaining time is larger than 1 Minute. - The maximum you substract from 300000 is 59999. Use timespan - (Date.now() % timespan) for the duration.

You are right, fixed - moved 'your code' under planing next run. Actualy you will subsctruct milliseconds only - this is adjustments to plan next loop in next 5min mark. And only after you plan next run you execute your main code.

I've edited answer.  Should work properly.

I tested it and it works fine on every 5 min but the problem is that it affects the running of the main function. Probably it is related to the conflict about delay parameter within the main function. As I said in my question, the main function has its own period, and your code caused its period to be reduced and inaccurate.

Here is a safer script. It will execute every time the interval gets a 5 minute mark and then it will move the entry to the end of the array. That means that there is room for some wobble
You can add checkTimeAndRunMainFunction() before the setInterval to run it immediately if the user starts it at an exact 5 minute time


const myFunction = () => {
  console.log("Function executed at:", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}

const getNearestFiveMinuteMark = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  return Math.ceil(minutes / 5) * 5;
}

const initializeFiveMinuteArray = () => {
  const nearestFiveMinuteMark = getNearestFiveMinuteMark();
  const intervals = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) { // 12 entries for every 5 minutes in an hour
    intervals.push((nearestFiveMinuteMark + i * 5) % 60);
  }
  return intervals;
}

const checkTimeAndRunMainFunction = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const currentMinute = now.getMinutes();

  if (currentMinute === fiveMinuteIntervals[0]) {
    // Run the main function and move the entry to the end
    myFunction();
    const executedEntry = fiveMinuteIntervals.shift();
    fiveMinuteIntervals.push(executedEntry);
  }
  time.textContent = `next run will be at :${String(fiveMinuteIntervals[0]).padStart(2,'0')}`;
}

const fiveMinuteIntervals = initializeFiveMinuteArray();
console.log("Initial 5-minute intervals array:", fiveMinuteIntervals);

// Set an interval to check the time every second
setInterval(checkTimeAndRunMainFunction, 1000);
<span id="time"></span>




The OP's problem has to be broken down ...

... into a generic solution for a function which calculates the amount of milliseconds until the next available slot for launching the interval of the OP's to be run/executed main task.

... and into a complete rewrite of the OP's checkTimeAndRunMainFunction function.


As for (1), the example code which gets provided after the explanation renames the OP's calculateDelayToNextFiveMinuteMark function to getTimeToNextAvailableSchedulerSlot and implements the calculation of the delay in a generic way, based on the to be passed slot precision in seconds, and does return the delay value in milliseconds in order to be as precise as possible.
As for (2), checkTimeAndRunMainFunction has to be entirely reimplemented as scheduleTask where the new function's 1st parameter is any function which one wants to be run/executed in a time slot based, scheduled way; its 2nd parameter equals the to be passed slot precision in seconds which will be used for both, calculating the delay until the schedule will be launched and setting the schedule's/task's interval.
scheduleTask in addition returns an object which features two properties timeout and interval which both are timer id's. Thus one can still prevent the launch of a schedule by clearing the timeout via timeout, and one can terminate an already running schedule/interval by clearing the interval via interval.


function getTimeToNextAvailableSchedulerSlot(slotPrecisionInSeconds) {
  const current = new Date;

  const precisionInMilliseconds = Number
    .isFinite(slotPrecisionInSeconds = parseInt(slotPrecisionInSeconds, 10))
      ? (slotPrecisionInSeconds * 1000)
      : 60_000; // 1 minute slot default.

  const currentMilliseconds = (
    current.getHours() * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
    current.getMinutes() * 60 * 1000 +
    current.getSeconds() * 1000 +
    current.getMilliseconds()
  );

  return (
    precisionInMilliseconds -
    (currentMilliseconds % precisionInMilliseconds)
  );
}

function scheduleTask(task, slotPrecisionInSeconds) {
  const timerIds = {
    timeout: null, interval: null,
  };
  const delay = getTimeToNextAvailableSchedulerSlot(slotPrecisionInSeconds);

  timerIds.timeout = setTimeout(() => {

    timerIds.interval = setInterval(task, slotPrecisionInSeconds * 1000);
    task();

  }, delay);

  return timerIds;
}


function chron_job_5_seconds_slot() {
  console.log('5 seconds chron job executed at ...', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
function chron_job_15_seconds_slot() {
  console.log('15 seconds chron job executed at ...', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
function chron_job_1_minute_slot() {
  console.log('1 minute chron job executed at ...', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
function chron_job_5_minutes_slot() {
  console.log('5 minutes chron job executed at ...', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
console.log('initialization started at ... ', new Date);

// execution at the next available 5 seconds slot continued with a 5 seconds interval.
const timer_ids_5_seconds_slot = scheduleTask(chron_job_5_seconds_slot, 5);

// execution at the next available 15 seconds slot continued with a 15 seconds interval.
const timer_ids_15_seconds_slot = scheduleTask(chron_job_15_seconds_slot, 15);

// execution at the next available 1 minute slot continued with a 1 minute interval.
const timer_ids_1_minute_slot = scheduleTask(chron_job_1_minute_slot, 60);

// execution at the next available 5 minutes slot continued with a 5 minutes interval.
const timer_ids_5_minutes_slot = scheduleTask(chron_job_5_minutes_slot, 5 * 60);


// terminate the 5 seconds based task immediately.
clearTimeout(timer_ids_5_seconds_slot.timeout);

// terminate all other tasks after 15 minutes.
setTimeout(() => {

  clearInterval(timer_ids_15_seconds_slot.interval);
  clearInterval(timer_ids_1_minute_slot.interval);
  clearInterval(timer_ids_5_minutes_slot.interval);

}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }





Pro tip
One can solve the problem of clocked functions/methods with a generic approach. Even better is implementing the generic approach as clocked method of e.g. Function.prototype.
The application/usage of the latter, in order to solve the OP's problem, then would be as simple as ...
// the OP's function.
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Function executed at:", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
// - create a variant of the OP's above function
//   with an interval clocked at (or set to) 5 minutes.
const clockedMyFct = myFunction.clocked(5 * 60 * 1000);

// // - whether to trigger an immediate or
// //   initial execution of `myFunction`.
// myFunction();

// - invoke/call the clocked variant of the OP's `myFunction`.
// - the latter is going to be invoked every 5 minutes and infinitely.
clockedMyFct();

But the clocked method implementation is capable of much more. One can customize the control-flow of any clocked function by providing an additional callback-function which acts as controller.
Having provided such a controller function, the latter gets invoked instead of the to be clocked function, but clocked at the same interval. The controller's sole parameter is a (clocked) data object which features everything one does need for manipulating the to be clocked function's control-flow.
One for instance can access a count value and a terminate function which makes it possible to terminate/clear the interval after a defined amount of executed intervals. A simple example demonstrates what was just said ...
// the OP's function.
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Function executed at:", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
// the controller function with a custom implemented control flow.
function controller(data) {
  const { clock: { count }, proceed, terminate } = data;

  if (count > 5) {

    terminate();

  } else {

    // - calling the function that needs
    //   to be executed in a clocked way.

    proceed();
  }
}
// - create a variant of the OP's above function with
//   an interval clocked at (or set to) 2 seconds which
//   terminates itself after having been invoked 5 times.
const clockedMyFct = myFunction.clocked(2_000, null, controller);

// // - whether to trigger an immediate or
// //   initial execution of `myFunction`.
// myFunction();

// - invoke/call the clocked variant of the OP's `myFunction`.
// - the latter is going to be invoked every 2 seconds and
//   to be terminated after having been invoked 5 times.
clockedMyFct();

And a possible implementation of a prototypal clocked method and some executable example code which creates and invokes various clocked versions according to the OP's problem looks as follows ...


function loggerOne() {
  console.log(
    `\nlogger ONE executed at ... ${ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }\n`
  );
}
function loggerTwo() {
  console.log(
    `logger TWO executed at ... ${ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }`
  );
}


function controller(clockedData) {
  const {
    clock: { interval, startTime, timestamp, count },
    target, args, proceed, terminate,
  } =
    clockedData;

  const passedTime = timestamp - startTime;
  const passedSeconds = passedTime / 1000;

  // - implement controller logic as you like/need.

  if (count > 10) {

    terminate();

  } else {
    console.log({
      interval,
      startTime,
      timestamp,
      passedSeconds,
      count,
      target,
      args,
      proceed,
    });

    // - calling the function that needs
    //   to be executed in a clocked way.

    proceed.apply(target, args);
  }
}
const clocked_at_20_seconds_cycling_infinitely =
  loggerOne.clocked(20_000);

const clocked_at_07_seconds_limited_to_10_cycles =
  loggerTwo.clocked(7_000, null, controller);


console.log(
  `... test started at ... ${ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }`
);
clocked_at_20_seconds_cycling_infinitely();
clocked_at_07_seconds_limited_to_10_cycles();
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
(function (Reflect, Math, Number, Array, Function) {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * @typedef {Object} clockedControllerClockData
   *  @param {number} interval  - interval-value in milliseconds.
   *  @param {number} startTime - time of first invocation in milliseconds.
   *  @param {number} timestamp - time of current invocation in milliseconds.
   *  @param {number} count     - current invocation-count since first invocation; `count` value of 1st invocation is `1`.
   */

  /**
   * A data object which holds all the necessary references
   * in order to properly run any controller logic.
   *
   * @typedef {Object} clockedControllerData
   *  @param {clockedControllerClockData} clock
   *  @param {(Object|null)} target
   *  @param {Array} args
   *  @param {Function} proceed
   *  @param {Function} terminate
   */

  /**
   * A callback function which acts like a pre-processor which e.g. can decide
   * whether to proceed with or terminate the original functions `clocked` version.
   *
   * @callback clockedController
   *  @param {clockedControllerData} data
   *   A data object which holds all the necessary references
   *   in order to properly run any controller logic.
   */

  const DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 200;

  const { isFinite, parseInt } = Number;

  function isFunction(value) {
    return (
      typeof value === 'function' &&
      typeof value.call === 'function' &&
      typeof value.apply === 'function'
    );
  }

  function getSanitizedInteger(value) {
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return isFinite(value) ? value : 0;
  }
  function getSanitizedPositiveInteger(value) {
    return Math.max(getSanitizedInteger(value), 0);
  }

  /**
   *  Returns a function, that, invoked initially once, will continuously auto-invoke
   *  the original function every amount of milliseconds, as it was parametrized by
   *  this methods `interval` argument. It does so until the additional `terminate`
   *  method of the returned wrapper function gets called.
   *  This methods second parameter - `target` - provides the object/context a `clocked`
   *  method can act upon.
   *  This methods third parameter - `controller` - enables the even more precise
   *  customized handling of how to run a `clocked` function/method.
   *
   * @param {number=} interval  - The optional interval value; expected to be grater than zero and assuming milliseconds.
   * @param {*=} target         - The function's/method's optional target object.
   * @param {clockedController=} controller
   *  The optional callback function which acts like a pre-processor where additionally
   *  provided program logic might e.g. decide whether to proceed with or terminate
   *  the original functions `clocked` version.
   * @returns {Function}
   *  The original function's/method's `clocked` version.
   */
  function createClockedFunction(interval/*, delay*/, target, controller) {
    const proceed = this;

    let thisArg;
    let argsArr;

    let clockCount = null;
    let clockStart = null;

    let timerId = null;

    target = target ?? null; // `null` instead of an `undefined` default.
    interval = getSanitizedPositiveInteger(interval) || DEFAULT_INTERVAL;

    function triggerController() {
      controller({
        clock: {
          interval,
          startTime: clockStart,
          timestamp: Date.now(),
          count: ++clockCount,
        },
        target: thisArg,
        args: [...argsArr],
        proceed,
        terminate,
      });
    }
    function triggerProceed() {
      proceed.apply(thisArg, argsArr);
    }

    function terminate() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      timerId = null;

      clockStart = null;
      clockCount = null;
    }

    function isActive() {
      return (timerId !== null);
    }

    function clocked(...argumentsArray) {
      // - a `clocked` method's target can be delegated at call time, thus
      //   it overrules the target which was provided at composition time.
      thisArg = (this ?? null) ?? target;
      argsArr = argumentsArray;

      if (isActive()) {
        terminate();
      }
      clockCount = 0;
      clockStart = Date.now();

      const trigger = isFunction(controller)
        ? triggerController
        : triggerProceed;

      timerId = setInterval(trigger, interval);
    }
    clocked.terminate = terminate;
    clocked.isActive = isActive;

    return (isFunction(proceed) && clocked) || proceed;
  }

  Reflect.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'clocked', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: createClockedFunction,
  });

}(Reflect, Math, Number, Array, Function));
</script>




@Hamed ... I did edit my (first) answer in a way that it first provides a solution for your problem of how to precisely launch time-slot and interval based chron jobs. My first answer which did not solve the real problem became the "Pro tip" section of both of my above provided solutions.
